# Excel 2013, how to sum up numbers across different sheets and rows?

Tags: excel, function

I have a 401k report on excel for the year.  I'm trying to do year end, but over the course of the year we hired and fired people.

Long story short, I have 52 sheets (1 for each week of the year) and I want to find a function in excel that will, find the persons name in column A on all the sheets and add there 401k amount which will be in column B across all 52 sheets.

Is that doable without manually finding them across 52 sheets and clicking with the SUM function?

My problem is for example I have John Smith in A1 but he may be on A3 or A10 because we hired people and fired people that moved his name around.

Comment: How are the sheets named?

Comment: See [This Site](https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets) it will show you how to do a sumif across many sheets.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare a new sheet in the beginning (Sheet1) that contains all the names of people across all 52 sheets in COLUMN A.
2. Put the formula in column B. See I have considered only 2 sheets in the formula for brevity. You need to repeat the "VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A$1:Sheet2!B$100,2,FALSE),0)" for all sheets. As you mentioned, the amount is assumed to be column B

=SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A$1:Sheet2!B$100,2,FALSE),0) + IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet3!A$1:Sheet3!B$100,2,FALSE),0))

Comment: Isn't there a maximum size for a formula?